# onPostExecute() does not send the intent to the onNewIntent() in the backgroud

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am facing problem with `onPostExecute()` in the background so I am  sending data like `long, lat, mac` to the server every 30 seconds and a response is coming back with the result as:

```
{
    "status":230,
    "routes":[9, 11],
    "distance":293.3018920430205
}
```

which are being processed well when the App runs in the front (the data is being passed to the onNewIntent method) but when it runs in the background  the  data is not being passed  to `onNewIntent` in the `MainActivity`  at all.
How can I get that to work to also send the route and the distance to the `MainActivity` when the app is running in the background?

```
public class PostData {
    String jSONString;


    // Context mContext;

    public PostData() {
        super();

    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;

    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public void post_data(String jSONString, Context context) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;

        new MyAsyncTask(context).execute(jSONString);
        //new MyAsyncTask(context).cancel(true);


    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        final Context mContext;
        ArrayList<Integer> routes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        double distance;

        public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground "
                        + params[0]);

                URL myUrl = new URL(
                        "https://tracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.connect();

                // System.out.println("The output of getResponsecode: "
                // + conn.getResponseCode());
                // create data output stream
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(params[0]);

                wr.close();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                StopsJSON data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), StopsJSON.class);

                routes = data.getRoutes();
                distance = data.getDistance();

                System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder: "
                        + sb.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // Intent with Conetxt of the Asyntask class and
            if (routes != null && !routes.isEmpty())  {
                // if(routes !=null ){
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("stop_route", routes);
                 intent.putExtra("stop_distance", distance);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the routes are null!!!");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

some of the MainActivity code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null) {
        double pLong = location.getLongitude();
        double pLat = location.getLatitude();


        String mac = get_mac_address();



        jSONString = convertToJSON(mac, pLong, pLat, time);

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            PostData sender = new PostData();
            sender.post_data(jSONString, bContext);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "The device is not connected to the internet ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please show your main activity code

Comment: Dude change your Asunch result parameter Void to Arraylist and in on postexecute check routes.size > 1. I think this will be work

Comment: from what context do you start your AsyncTask?

Comment: @OlegOsipenko: I am starting it from the passed MainActvity context to the inner  `MyLocationListener` Please see my MainActivity code.

Comment: @tree as FunkTheMonk's already mentioned activity can't make background job, use service for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activities are not meant to be ran in the background. Use a Service instead.

Also, onNewIntent will only be called when an instance of the Activity already exists, and it has the correct flags set in the AndroidManifest.xml or the intent that is starting it.

Comment: worth to mention using of Pending Intent also

Comment: Does that mean I have to replace the Activity with Service class? Also in my App the user will need the UI app sometime to see the Location of the buses or to input some data. On the other Hand, the app should be able to run in the Background and interact with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is the Android component with UI. Cause UI takes a lot of memory Android framework stops and clears all UI-related components when application gone to the background in order to release memory - you activity stops as long as AsyncTask started from it. So if you need your task to be done in background you have to use another Android component, which doesn't need UI - the Service.

For starting activity from this background service you need to use PendingIntent. And for updating the UI with results of this background task your Activity can bind to the server, or you can use Messenger to communicate from service to Activity. Or your service could store results in the ContentProvider or database and then your activity could take any information it needs from there. Also consider using some sort of EventBus - either Otto or GreenBus - for this purpose

Comment: In the Background I am getting the updated Long and lat from the onLocationChanged method also the activity is not being canceled!?

Comment: task is working but Activity is dead. But all Activity-related objects still in memory holding by the reference from AsyncTask and can't be GCed. That is called memory leak